# Exhange two variables passed by reference won't cooperate

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Please consider the below MASM assembly code snippet.  As is, it will jmp to skip2 and works just fine.  Comment out the jmp skip2 line and the first half executes - actually it doesn't. Instead, in VS2015 debug mode, I get an access violation error.  I've attached an excel diagram of my interpretation of the stack activation record. Under (1) is esp and the offsets - this works fine if you jmp to skip2.

Under (2) is ebp and its offsets (I think), which would say [ebp+40] and [ebp+44] should work. It doesn't, nor does my other naïve thought (3) that maybe with pushad, that is the correct place to start with ebp.  Green shows the result of the stack following the pushad instruction.  Yellow shows the targets, namely @I and @k, that obviously need to be dereferenced.

Where am I going wrong?

```
Exchange    PROC
    pushad
    jmp skip2    ; comment this jmp instruction out and works fine. 
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+44]       ; eax gets @k
    mov ecx, [eax]          ; ecx gets k.
    mov ebx, [ebp+40]       ; ebx gets @i.
    mov edx, [ebx]          ; edx gets i.
    mov [eax], edx          ; k = i.
    mov [ebx], ecx          ; i = k.
    pop     ebp        ; EDITED:  THIS IS THE FIX
    jmp ende
skip2:
    mov eax, [esp+40]       ; eax gets @k
    mov ecx, [eax]          ; ecx gets k.
    mov ebx, [esp+36]       ; ebx gets @i.
    mov edx, [ebx]          ; edx gets i.
    mov [eax], edx          ; k = i.
    mov [ebx], ecx          ; i = k.
ende:
    popad
    ret 8
Exchange    ENDP
```

[image]

Comment: You do `push ebp` without `pop ebp` which messes up the stack before the jump to `ende:`.

Comment: Thanks, but no, same issue.  Added pop ebp right before ret 8. ****EDIT: But if you put it in front of jmp ende it works.  Answer it?

Comment: Not before `ret 8`, but before `jmp ende`. Stack is LIFO(last-in-first-out). Aside from that, the `PROC` directive would take care of the immediate after `ret`, so use `ret` instead of `ret 8`.

Comment: You don't need `pusha` / `popa`.  Just save/restore any call-preserved registers you want to use.  (You're normally allowed to clobber eax, ecx, and edx without saving/restoring them.)  You definitely don't need to save `ebp` twice, since `pusha` already saves it.

Comment: I think the excel spreadsheet and good comments in the code to explain what you thought should be going on deserves an upvote, even though you didn't actually show any output from your *debugger* about where the access violation happened.  (what instruction and what register contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just missing the pop ebp as is pointed out in the comments...